# Using System.Linq.Expressions to span a tuple in an array of object [C#]

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Let's suppose I've a method like this

```
public static int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I need to construct an expression so that the new method must be returned in the form `new object[1]{Sum(a, b);}` and to do so I use this code:

```
var callMethod = Expression.Call(mi, parameters);

// new object[] { Sum((a, b) }
var returnResult = Expression.NewArrayInit(
    typeof(object),
    Expression.Convert(callMethod, typeof(object)));
```

where `mi` is the Sum method taken via reflection.

Now, I need to extend the generation of the expression to manage a tuple as output paramert and the result of the tuple must be spanned into the result array.. Pratically, what I would like to do is converting this method

```
public static (int result, bool isOverflowed) Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b, false);
}
```

into this:

```
 var callMethod = Expression.Call(mi, parameters);

// new object[] { Sum((a, b) }
var returnResult = Expression.NewArrayInit(
    typeof(object),
    Expression.Convert(Tuple1, typeof(object)),  // The desired
    Expression.Convert(Tuple2, typeof(object))); // The desired
```

How this can be accomplished?

Comment: You could call "Item1" and "Item2" property getters.

Comment: Thanks @SohaibJundi Jundi, And how to get them from the MethodCallExpression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method will return `ValueTuple<int, bool>`, it is possible to get the values from `Item1` and `Item2` fields. The basic idea is to assign the method return to a variable and get `Item1` and `Item2` fields.

```
var mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Sum");
var parameters = new ParameterExpression[]{ Expression.Parameter(typeof(int)), Expression.Parameter(typeof(int)) };
var callMethod = Expression.Call(mi, parameters);
var variable = Expression.Variable(typeof(ValueTuple<int, bool>));
var assign = Expression.Assign(variable, callMethod);
var returnResult = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object),
  Expression.Convert(Expression.Field(variable, "Item1"), typeof(object)),
  Expression.Convert(Expression.Field(variable, "Item2"), typeof(object)));
var block = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[] { variable }, assign, returnResult);

var x = Expression.Lambda(block, parameters).Compile().DynamicInvoke(1 , 2);
```